# Insert in looping cause the column count doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to post something into table in array (which may be more than one value for each column)

If I post only one value with the code bellow, it posted the value successfully into the database table.

However, if I posted two values, it can't. An error shows "Column count doesn't match"

Here is my query.

```
        $quantity = explode("|",$_POST['esquantity']);
        $order_id = explode("|",$_POST['size']);
        $member_id = $_SESSION['login_id'];


            $result = "INSERT INTO estockresult (items,
                                            id_cart,
                                            customer_id, 
                                            esquantity,
                                            reference_no, 
                                            size)

                                    SELECT  items,
                                            '$random', 
                                            '$member_id',
                                            '".implode("', '", $quantity)."',
                                            reference_no, 
                                            size

                                    FROM    estock_orders
                                    WHERE   id in (".implode(',',$order_id).")
                ";

                $res = $mysqli->query($result);

            if (!$res) {
                printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
                }
```

Thanks for having a look and the help.

Comment: SQL does not store arrays, as a data type. Your code needs to insert one row per value you want to add to the table, or you need your array column to be storing text, not numbers.

Comment: Can you please give me another method of SQL on how to do this (you must understand what the code about is going to achieve)

Comment: The problem is that your table definition probably has esquantity as an integer, and you are inserting more than one integer. Instead of what you did, loop through your array in PHP and insert them as multiple different rows, one per array element.

Comment: Wait, the type of the column of esquantity is varchar in the database, even though what I will always insert into there is integer.

Comment: the thing which is interger is the `id` which must also auto increament. Is that a problem?

Comment: The below answer should do it; you would now pass a single string of comma separated values, instead of a comma separated list of literals, which is interpreted as multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to insert one row per value you want to add to the table, or you need your array column to be storing an array. Here is how to do the second, simply by not passing the items as multiple items, but as one comma separated list:

```
    $quantity = explode("|",$_POST['esquantity']);
    $order_id = explode("|",$_POST['size']);
    $member_id = $_SESSION['login_id'];


        $result = "INSERT INTO estockresult (items,
                                        id_cart,
                                        customer_id, 
                                        esquantity,
                                        reference_no, 
                                        size)

                                SELECT  items,
                                        '$random', 
                                        '$member_id',
                                        '".implode(",", $quantity)."',
                                        reference_no, 
                                        size

                                FROM    estock_orders
                                WHERE   id in (".implode(',',$order_id).")
            ";

            $res = $mysqli->query($result);

        if (!$res) {
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a great way to store your data; you probably want quantities that can be summed, and what you store here is not just strings, but strings that in the case that was breaking things, contain multiple values.